# extract a line matching a phrase

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a whole line matching a word/phrase on that line!
I tried this:

```
preg_match("/PHRASE/i", $dictionary,$matches);
```

But I get only the matched word! but I need that whole line! And there more than 15K lines!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
^.*PHRASE.*$
```

`^` to match the start of the line

`.*` to match any number of characters except newlines

`PHRASE` to match your keyword/phrase

`.*` as above

`$` to match the end of the line.

You might also want to surround your `PHRASE` with word boundary anchors (if your phrase is indeed a word or words): `^.*\bPHRASE\b.*$` will match only if `PHRASE` is on its own (and not part of another word like `PHRASEBOOK`).

So, if you are applying your regex to every single line separately, use

```
preg_match('/^.*PHRASE.*$/i', $dictionary, $matches)
```

If you have all your lines inside a long multiline string and want to iterate over all the lines that contain your phrase, use:

```
preg_match_all('/^.*PHRASE.*$/im', $dictionary, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $matches[0][$i];
}
```

Note the `/m` modifier to allow `^` and `$` to match at the start and end of each line (instead of just start/end of the string).

Comment: It worked after I added /m modifier! thanks! however, I surprised seeing the comparison of two solution given by you (Tim Pietzcker) and RobertPitt! Secon one (regex) takes about: 0.022 Seconds including file_get_contents(). but the first one (stripos) including file() takes about 0.0141 Seconds! Isn't it surprising? I believe regex will be much faster!

Comment: btw, there is a study() function in PERL to optimize the string before matching, specially where repeated matchings are available! is there anything such for PHP?

Comment: @HungryCoder, regex is usually slower than a couple of "normal" string operations like `strpos(...)`. Note however that such 0.022 vs. 0.0141 are no reliable numbers. For a a more reliable comparison, you'd have to perform the test at least a couple of thousand times and then take the average of it.

Comment: Are you including file_get_contents() within the speed tracking of the regex?

Comment: yes, i am including file_get_contents inside the time tracking!

Comment: not average, I just executed both stuff inside for() loop for 1000 times! regex taken 15.7409 Seconds and stripos 15.248 Seconds.

Comment: however, stripos is taking much more time than strpos! about 10 seconds more! so now regex is taking 15+ seconds and stripos is taking 24+ seconds. but I don't see significant time change if I keep or remove the /i modifier from regex! so, I guess I can go with regex than stripos!

Answer (score 3):

Use something like:

```
$handle = @fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    $matches = array();
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(stripos($buffer,"mystring") !== false)
        {
            $matches[] = $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Then you can see the results in `$matches`

Comment: thanks sir for your answer! it worked! please check my comparison below!

Comment: You should use `stripos` instead as the original regular expression has the *i* modifier.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about it, thanks! the comparison is significant after I did this!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about case-sensitivity :) +1

Answer (score 1):

try

```
preg_grep('/whatever/', file('filename'));
```

[file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) — Reads entire file into an array

[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) — Return array entries that match the pattern

Comment: nice using `preg_grep` and `file` ina 1 line situation, but when dealing with string comparisons you should take in the speed of them 2 functions in comparison with alternative methods.