# RegEx.test() vs Comparison Operator Performance

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there are any major performance differences between the following. Obviously there is a nice tidiness to the first.

```
var value = 'a';

if (/^[a-d]$/.test(value)) {
    // do something...
}
```

and

```
if (value === 'a' || value === 'b' || value === 'c' || value === 'd') {
    // do something
}
```

I did find this, but it seems to be server side based, rather than client side (this is for an iOS web app):

['Regular Expression' VS 'String Comparison operators / functions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749886/regular-expression-vs-string-comparison-operators-functions)

Comment: these are missing the `^$` to be equivalent

Comment: The second one is most likely faster, in this case.

Comment: `/a/` is not the same as `=== 'a'`. However, `/^a$/` is.